# What is the fastest way to find the exact solution of a linear system, matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a linear system (A*x=B) where  B is a 64-bit length or more. I have used linsolve function in Matlab to solve the system of equations. I have used (inv(A)*B), A\B, and ttimes(A,B) as well, and they suffer from the same issues.

I am facing two problems:

1. linslove function cannot find the exact solution if ( A and B) are not symbolic.
2. If A and B are symbolic, linsolve manage to find the exact solution but it takes too much time.

Is there any way to find the exact solution but fast.

```
time=[]
i=50
a=magic(i);    
% B is a rendom numbers where each number is 64 bit length
B=double(bi2de(randi([0 1],i,64)));

%%****************************************
 % to make sure th matrix is not  **ill-conditioned***
        C = 1;              % desired condition number
        [u s v] = svd(a);
        s = diag(s);        % s is vector
        % ===== linear stretch of existing s
        s = s(1)*( 1-((C-1)/C)*(s(1)-s)/(s(1)-s(end)));
        % =====
        s = diag(s);           % back to matrix
        A = u*s*v';
%%****************************************
tic
x1=linsolve(A,B);
time(1,1)=toc;
%-------------------------------------
% convert A and B into symbolic 
Aa=sym(A);        Bb=sym(B);
tic
x2=linsolve(Aa,Bb);
time(1,2)=toc;
%-------------------------------------
% Show the accuracy of the first B(1), exact vs computed 
Exact=sym(double(B(1)))     
Computed=[ A(1,:)*x1  Aa(1,:)*x2]
time
```

x1 and x2 are the two solution. x2 is the solution of the sumbolic A and B.

Only X2 gives us the exact solution

```
Exact solution =   2350911785583947776
Computed using x1= 2350911785583965184
Computed using x2= 2350911785583947776
```

Time required in seconds:

```
x1 time =    0.0007
x2 time =    6.7242
```

Comment: part of the problem might be that you're getting close to the limit of double precision

Comment: In this code no. If I increase B more than 256-bit, I got (inf), which means I have reached the double precision.

Comment: Double precision has 15 digits of precision. You cannot expect the lower digits past 15 to be meaningful, let alone correct. Why do you need an exact solution to so many digits? Why do you think this precision is important? Very few real-world problems need this kind of precision, because the inputs are imprecise as well. Note that your 64-bit integers are already approximated when you converted them to doubles in `B`. Therefore, your "exact solution" using the symbolic toolbox is not exact either.

Comment: I need the exact because I am hiding information and i want to retrieve it back.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question, it is a demonstration of why your "exact" solution is not exact: the intput `B` is approximated. Try this in MATLAB:

```matlab
a = randi([0 1],1,64);
a(1) = 0;
a1 = bi2de(a);
a(1) = 1;
a2 = bi2de(a);
a1-a2
```

You'll notice that `a1` and `a2` are identical, even though I flipped the least significant bit in both numbers. This is because a double-precision float cannot hold 64 bits of precision. It holds only 52. The other 12 bits in the 64-bit representation are to store the sign bit and the exponent (which scales the number).

Comment: Thank you. I haven't think about this issue and I didn't know it is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have built my own bi2de that converts the binary vector to an actual number.

I have replaced sym by vpa, and the performance enhanced.

sym(A) ----> vpa(A)